# java input output test through GUI

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-7

Hi guys please let me know where i am wrong while trying yo run this program and getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException` error

```
 import javax.swing.*; 
 public class InputOutputTest { 
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
   //takes input through GUI 
   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enternumber"); 
   int number = Integer.parseInt(input); 
   int square = number * number; 
   //Display square on console 
   System.out.println("square:" + square); 
   //Display square on GUI 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "square:"+ square); 
   System.exit(0); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: enter number in `InputDialog`. it must not contain any alphabet or symbol character.

Answer (score 3):

You should enter only numbers in the input dialog. the parseInt is causing the exception. Add error handling like below

```
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number");
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int square = number * number;
            System.out.println("square:" + square);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "square:" + square);
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only Numbers are accepted");
        }
```